# Constantly being unable to deploy app on app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using google app engine launcher, I can't seem to deploy my app due to this:
email=martinchua99@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\school work\customtinywebdb']"
Usage: appcfg.py [options] update  | [file, ...]

appcfg.py: error: Error parsing C:\Users\admin\Desktop\school work\customtinywebdb\app.yaml: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\school work\customtinywebdb\app.yaml", line 1, column 24.
2014-11-25 19:46:48 (Process exited with code 2)

This is my yaml file,whats wrong with it?

application: camel-cars: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: .*
  script: main.py

Comment: delete one line at a time util it works, then you've found the problem line.

Answer (score 0):

Yaml files are sensitive to white spaces. Also you are missing key words and new lines. Give this a try:

```
application: camel-cars
version: 1 
runtime: python27 
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: .* 
  script: main.py
```

Comment: 2014-11-26 23:35:33 Running command: "[u'C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=martinchua99@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', u'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\school work\\customtinywebdb']"
Usage: appcfg.py [options] update <directory> | [file, ...]

appcfg.py: error: Error parsing C:\Users\admin\Desktop\school work\customtinywebdb\app.yaml: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\school work\customtinywebdb\app.yaml", line 9, column 15.
Used your code, this came up, what should i do?

Comment: I think I messed up when copying, try the above again. A good place to test is here: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/